# UIImage Animation Crashes Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimage, theos

Hi guys I have been trying to develop a cydia that will animate a image inside a UIImageView, and I think that my code is all good but for some reason the app just crashes every time that perform the task. I have read that this could be the cause of loading too many images at once but I'm only trying to load 2 small png images so i don't think that could be the cause. Please let me know what you think!

```
%hook UISaveToCameraRollActivity
-(void)performActivity {
%orig;
NSBundle *bundle = [[NSBundle alloc] initWithPath:kBundlePath];
NSString *imagePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"hand" ofType:@"png"];
NSString *imagePath1 = [bundle pathForResource:@"floppy" ofType:@"png"];
UIWindow *statusWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]
bounds]];
statusWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
statusWindow.hidden = NO;
statusWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.7];
UIImageView *pic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0, 0, 69, 69)];
pic.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"hand.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"floppy.png"], nil];
pic.animationDuration = 1.0f;
[pic startAnimating];
pic.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[pic release];
pic.center = statusWindow.center;
pic.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
pic.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath1];
[statusWindow addSubview:pic];
[statusWindow makeKeyAndVisible];

}
%end
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on non-arc memory management, but why are you releasing pic and then in the next line trying to use it again?

Comment: this is not enough information to help. post a stack trace of the crash, for starters.

Comment: idk how to do a stack trace but isn't there enough info in the code to find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move:

```
[pic release];
```

to the end of your method. You should NEVER interact with an object once you release it, this is almost a guaranteed way to crash your app.

If you do not want to be bothered with manually managing memory, you should give ARC a try:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Hi JustAnotherCoder, thank you so much for your reply! I put the           [pic release];under the pic.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath1]; but it still crashed then i put     [pic release]; under [statusWindow makeKeyAndVisible]; and it only showed the floppy image and didn't animate. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: You must add it to subview BEFORE animating. So try and move [statusWindow addsSubview:pic] before [pic startAnimating]

Comment: ok I did what you said and its still only showing the floppy image. Here is the code.                                                [statusWindow addSubview:pic];
[statusWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
[pic startAnimating];
pic.animationRepeatCount = 9;
pic.center = statusWindow.center;
pic.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
pic.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath1];

Comment: never mind i got it all working thanks a lot for your help man!